# String comparison without CASE statements?

Tags: sql-server, case, string

Is there a shorter more terse way to do a string comparison in SQL Server without wrapping it in a `CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 END`? In PostgreSQL, I can do

```
SELECT c, c='foo'
FROM ( VALUES ('foo'),('bar') ) AS t(c);
```

In SQL Server, I have to do

```
SELECT c, CASE WHEN c='foo' THEN 1 END
FROM ( VALUES ('foo'),('bar') ) AS t(c);
```

In the abstract, is there an easier more SQL-Servery way to throw an expression into boolean context? Or, is there a better way to write `strcmp` without rolling your own case statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that you'd call it shorter, but you could use the [Logical Function `IIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). From the docs,

> **`IIF` is a shorthand way for writing a `CASE` expression.** It evaluates the Boolean expression passed as the first argument, and then returns either of the other two arguments based on the result of the evaluation.

Per the example,

```
SELECT c, iif(c='foo',1,0)
FROM ( VALUES ('foo'),('bar') ) AS t(c);
```

Comment: Very cool, that's exactly what I was looking for! Though not having true/false defaults implicit is a tragedy.

Comment: I can understand that Evan, especially after reading your profile :) Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 0):

For fun, here is another way of doing a string comparison to get a binary result out.  Just join a table on with the "true" parts of your case and put a 1 for the second column.

```
SELECT t.c, COALESCE(p.b, 0) AS b
FROM ( VALUES ('foo'),('bar') ) AS t(c)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (VALUES ('foo', 1)) AS p(c,b) ON p.c = t.c;
```